# Next element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find the next element with a given class after the element which trigged the event, regardless of the position of the searched element.
Let’s say I have multiple pairs of inputs. One with the class „dynamic“ and the other one with the class „fit“.

Regardless of what’s inbetween the two inputs I want to copy the value of .dynamic and past it into the next input with the class .fit .

I tried multiple things and came the closest with going back to the parent element and find the input with the class „.fit“ – but as soon as there are multiple pairs of inputs within the same parent this does not work anymore.
Any ideas how to solve that problem?

```js
$('.dynamic').each(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent().find("input.fit").val(value);

});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}

input {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
}

.fit {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <input type="text" class="dynamic" value="Value 1 " />
  <input type="text" class="fit" value="-----" />

  <br>

  <input type="text" class="dynamic" value="Value 2" />
  <div>Something random here</div>
  <input type="text" class="fit" value="-----" />

</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nextAll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple--you want to use `.nextAll()` to select all the trailing inputs, and pick the first one, i.e.: `$(this).nextAll("input.fit").first().val(value)`

The reason why `.next()` will not work is because it only checks the immediate sibling. For the second set of input pairs (with `value2`), as you have other DOM nodes in between, `.next('input.fit')` this will return nothing as the argument serves as a filter. Since the next DOM element is a `<div>` element, it will not pass the filter and hence will not work as expected.

```js
$('.dynamic').each(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(this).nextAll("input.fit").first().val(value);

});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}

input {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
}

.fit {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <input type="text" class="dynamic" value="Value 1 " />
  <input type="text" class="fit" value="-----" />

  <br>

  <input type="text" class="dynamic" value="Value 2" />
  <div>Something random here</div>
  <input type="text" class="fit" value="-----" />

</div>
```

Comment: why posting same answer again?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar We were composing the answers at the same time, but I had perform testing using OP's code and submitted later, after which I only realised you have also answered. And my answer is not the same as yours.

Comment: Make sense. now there are 3 answer in total doing more or less same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much especially for the demo, simpler than I tought!

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Multiple answers converging to a similar solution should be seen as a good sign, not a bad one.

Comment: @Milind Anantwar, In order to be an answer the response in  each case should solve the problem.  That is, literally doing the same thing, no matter the syntactical form of the response.

Answer (score 3):

Try chaining nextAll() and first() with jQuery, like so:

```
$(this).nextAll('input.fit').first().val(myval);
```

NextAll will find any elements that are siblings of, but after, `$(this)`. First will prevent your val call from affecting any input but the first.

Comment: My mistake - I misread the requirements :( thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Also, OP, if you have the option you really should just use cleaner markup. Having to do this just feels wrong.

Comment: @BillCriswell - what would you suggest? I am more than happy for better solutions.

Comment: You could add potentially a second className, a matching classname for two elements that fire together, with some prefix that would make it easy to find such as "group-1"

Comment: Performance doesn't matter right now. It's going to be a maintainability nightmare down the line for you and not straight-forward for whoever comes along next.

Comment: I'd personally wrap inputs that are related in a common parent and loop through those. I'd iterate over `.group`'s here: `<div class="wrapper"><div class="group"><input><input></div> <div class="group"><input><input></div></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) with [:first](http://api.jquery.com/:first/) selector here:

> .nextAll() - Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
>
> :first -Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

```
$('.dynamic').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var value = $this.val();
   $this.nextAll("input.fit").val(value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much - really helped me!